# Сложносочиненное предложение, одна из частей которого в повелительном наклонении

Tags: пунктуация

`Оставьте номер Вашего телефона, и мы перезвоним Вам!` Как я это вижу, запятая нужна, потому что это два предложения в составе сложносочинённого, просто у первого из них нет подлежащего. Но нет ли подводных камней? Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сложносочиненное предложение с двумя грамматическими основами, поэтому запятая нужна. 
Также можно поставить тире: "Оставьте свой номер телефона - и мы перезвоним!"